# Do not declare C-style arrays, use std::array<> instead

Tags: c++, arrays, clang-tidy

From clang-tidy I get for

```
struct Foo {
private:
  static constexpr char BAR[] = "\033[2J";
};
```

the warning

> do not declare C-style arrays, use std::array<> instead
>   [cppcoreguidelines-avoid-c-arrays]

for BAR.

How can I declare with

```
#include <array>
struct Foo {
private:
  static constexpr std::array<char,7> BAR // = ???
};
```

Thanks

Comment: (You probably don't want to omit the trailing `\0` but the dupe shows how that is accomplished too).

Answer (score 3):

That's just:

```
std::array<char, 5> BAR{ '\033', '[', '2', 'J', 0 };
```

Comment: This works but is needlessly verbose. You can just do `... BAR{"\033[2J"};`.